# "Had I better go (or gone) with you?" -- which verb to use there?

Tags: sentence-construction

I just came across the following sentence (which can be found [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Had%20I%20better%20go%20with%20you%3F%22&rlz=1C1GCEU_enPK819PK819&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi_nOzhpLHhAhXCxoUKHQx8CCMQ_AUIEigA&biw=1535&bih=794));

> Had I better go with you?

I think, that is correct; I just don't know what the context/meaning would be!

Amazingly, [Google-ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Had%20I%20better%20go%2CHad%20I%20better%20gone&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CHad%20I%20better%20go%3B%2Cc0) found the frequencies of only the original one.

Should there be a past-participle used, eg;

> Had I better gone with you? (This one makes no sense to me either!)

Is there any other (better) way of expressing the POV of the actual sentence?

Comment: Where did you find the original sentence? It looks incorrect to me. A context to this sentence / question would help for understanding better the meaning.

Comment: @virotino The original sentence is probably interrogative form of "I had better go with you.". However, I still doubt. See: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22I+had+better+go+with+you.%22&rlz=1C1GCEU_enPK819PK819&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiPl6nmx7HhAhWk2eAKHQncChwQ_AUIEigA&biw=1535&bih=794

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the first sentence. The second is ungrammatical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> There is nothing wrong with the first sentence. The second is ungrammatical. -- Jason Bassford.

The original sentence is an interrogative form of "I had better go with you.".